# android fragment crashes on resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I know this is not a question but I've been struggling with this issue for a long time, whenever i work with `fragments`, when I leave the app (not destroyed, just click on home button) and I return to it after some amount of time, it gives `nullpointerexception` for all my variables and everything, I know this is a memory issue where it clears some space for other apps, but how can I workaround this and protect my objects from beeing destroyed,
thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at
[onSaveInstanceState(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

This gets called when user minimizes your app -> by hitting the home button or when the OS is about to destroy your app.  At this point you can save all the needed variables in the bundle that is passed in.  This bundle is written to disk and passed back when your activity is recreated:
If you just want to retrieve your variables in the Activity you can use:

[protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Fragment do not have onRestoreInstanceState(...) but you can use [onActivityCreated(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) to access the bundle if you want to retrieve your variables in the fragment.